# HighlIght search term using javascript in an html

Tags: javascript

this is my scenario ; I have an html as below, how can I highlight the search term in the results using Javascript ?

I mean when I type  : Ho -> the first 2 letter of HOME will be highlighted.
If I search for HOME : the whole word in the result will be highlighted.

Comment: Where's the code? What have you tried?

Comment: 1 hour ago was question like this with working example code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17520307/2524304

Comment: @FSou1, good suggestion. Note that that example has jQuery.

Comment: Think, how to highlight a sub-string in a string, so concept will be more clear. Post some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510852/highlight-search-term-in-javascript-according-to-term/17511124#17511124

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example:

**HTML**

```
Search: <input id="test"/>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var results = ["Result1 Description", "Result2 Description", "Result3 Description"];

$("#test").change(function(){
    $("#results").empty();
var searchTerm = $(this).val();


for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    if(results[i].indexOf(searchTerm) != -1){

        $("#results").append("<li>"+ results[i].replace(searchTerm, "<span class=\"wrap\">" + searchTerm + "</span>") + "</li>");
    }
}
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/t3BZ6/

Comment: @BrianTimJesus Are you viewing the example or copying and pasting the code?  In the example, try typing `sult` in the textbox then firing the change event by pressing tab.