# simple search through 2 columns in single model, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have simple search (I want to keep that way)  where I can make search Product name. But I want to add other column(Still Product model) intro_text.

Code so far:

**Product.rb**

```
def self.search(search)  
  if search  
   where('intro_text LIKE ? ', "%#{search}%")
  else     
   where('name LIKE ? ', "%#{search}%")    
 end  
end
```

**Search controller**

```
@products_search = Product.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
```

At this point when search occurs results are displayed just from **intro_text** field.
Demo:
Searching for phrase "Pez" should find all products that consists of this phrase and also all products that intro text consists of this phrase.

Also tried to :

```
 def self.search(search)  
     if search  
        where('intro_text LIKE ? ', "%#{search}%") || where('name LIKE ? ', "%#{search}%")
     else  
     end  
 end
```

But the result  was the same!
Can somebody give me some tip?
I don't need any search gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `params[:search]` has no value, then the `else` clause becomes:

```
where('name LIKE "%%"')
```

which isn't very helpful.

In the second example you posted, the first `where()` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and will always be trueish, so the `||` will never get triggered.

Also, using the same name for a local variable as the method is a little confusing.

Looks to me like you want a combined OR search?

```
def self.search(search_term)
  if search_term.present?
    where('intro_text LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%", "%#{search_term}%")
  else
    none # new in Rails 4, or you can do where('1 = 0')
         # for a scope that will never return records, but can still
         # chain your pagination, etc onto
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks worked just great. But at this point,it is possible to somehow highlight found phrases in search results ? Without any gem ?

Comment: If you are looping over results before printing, then you could replace them inline with a `span` that you can apply styling to: `new_result = result.gsub(params[:search], "<span style='background-color: yellow;'>#{params[:search]}</span>")` or use a JavaScript implementation like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521399/highlight-search-term-using-javascript-in-an-html